# Numbers not displaying correctly in Chromium

Tags: fonts, chromium

On Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, Chromium just started to not display numbers correctly in the command line.  Letters display fine, but numbers don't: [image: screenshot]
I tried rebooting, uninstalling and reinstalling Chromium, as well as changing fonts in the settings, but the issue remains.  It also is showing blocky letters in the extensions (see the "13" in the Todoist extension (red square) in the screenshot).  Fonts seem to be fine elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling an application won't normally delete the personal configurations and plugins a user has inadvertently installed.  The new version or fresh install will load the configuration which in your case may be corrupted.

Completely remove all configurations from Chromium from your configuration file with these commands:

```
$ cd ~/.config
$ mv chromium chromium.bak
```

After that step, you'll no longer have any of your previous settings, saved password, or plugin when you start chromium.  It'll create a new `~/.config/chromium` folder.

You can then systematically configure the new Chromium environment being careful with which extensions or configurations to activate.

To switch back to your previous Chromium environment, rename your new chromium `chromium.new` and the backup (chromium.bak) to `chromium`.

If you have signed into chromium, most of your settings will be automatically brought to the new install.  If that happens, systematically uninstall or disable all your plugins and extensions from the signed in environment.